# Rails redirect_to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a `filter_before` filter that checks to see if a param is true. If it is my app does this.  However, the `&& return` seems to be causing some problems.  When I take it out, it'll redirect form every page to the desired `countdown` page--but then it loops or double renders.

```
redirect_to :countdown && return if @online == 1
```

Is there a way to wrap this in an if statement?

Something like:

```
if current_page(:countdown)
  redirect_to :countdown if @online == 1
end
```

Comment: IMHO (at least, it's the way I proceed): when people provide me with good answers, I give them a +1, if someone answers my question, I give + 1 and I accept the answer. I'm not begging for points but I feel like Scott deserve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better exclude the `countdown` action from your `before_filter` to avoid infinite loop.

something like:

```
before_filter :check_countdown, :except => :countdown
```

That said, what you did is valid:

```
  redirect_to :countdown and return if @online == 1
```

Comment: This makes so much sense...shoulda thought of that myself!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `and` instead of `&&`.

From the Rails Guide:

> Make sure you use **and return** and not **&& return** because while the
>   former will work, the latter will not due to operator precedence in
>   the Ruby Language.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Scott, I appreciate you answer, but I'm a first-grader rails student right now and I'm new to programming in general, so while your answer is probably correct, it makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Fair enough. I wish you luck with your Ruby studies! :-)

Comment: Your answer helped me! +1

Answer (score 0):

It might be work for you

```
return redirect_to :countdown if @online == 1
```